# Updating a field depending on the value outcome of a SUM on a other table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Because our ERP supplier recently switched to another database (from ADS to PostgreSQL), there is still too little knowledge within our organization about working with the PostgreSQL language. We used to process the following manually once a year, with separate SQL scripts, but now that our organization is growing, this is becoming increasingly difficult. I'm looking for a solution to the problem below, preferably in the form of a PostgreSQL script.

The problem:

There are 2 tables, INVOICE and CUSTOMERS.
The DEBTOR_NUMBER is unique in both tables. Furthermore, these tables are not related to each other.

In the INVOICE table, the total turnover of the previous year must be added up per DEBIT_NUMBER.
Depending on the turnover made, a field must be filled in in the CUSTOMERS table.

```
If the previous years turnover made for the INVOICE.DEBTOR_NUMBER, SUM(INVOICE.TURNOVER) > 100,000 the CUSTOMERS.CLASS_CUSTOMER field must be filled with the text 'AA', where CUSTOMERS.DEBTOR_NUMBER = INVOICE.DEBTOR_NUMBER
If the previous years turnover made for the INVOICE.DEBTOR_NUMBER, SUM(INVOICE.TURNOVER) > 20,000 and < 100,000 then fill the CUSTOMERS.CLASS_CUSTOMER field with the text 'A', where CUSTOMERS.DEBTOR_NUMBER = INVOICE.DEBTOR_NUMBER
If the previous years turnover made for the INVOICE.DEBTOR_NUMBER, SUM(INVOICE.TURNOVER) > 6,000 and < 20,000 then fill the CUSTOMERS.CLASS_CUSTOMER field with the text 'B', where CUSTOMERS.DEBTOR_NUMBER = INVOICE.DEBTOR_NUMBER
If the previous years turnover made for the INVOICE.DEBTOR_NUMBER, SUM(INVOICE.TURNOVER) > 0 and < 6,000 then fill the CUSTOMERS.CLASS_CUSTOMER field with the text 'C', where CUSTOMERS.DEBTOR_NUMBER = INVOICE.DEBTOR_NUMBER
If the previous years turnover made for the INVOICE.DEBTOR_NUMBER, SUM(INVOICE.TURNOVER) = 0 then fill the CUSTOMERS.CLASS_CUSTOMER field with the text 'D', where CUSTOMERS.DEBTOR_NUMBER = INVOICE.DEBTOR_NUMBER
If the previous years turnover made for the INVOICE.DEBTOR_NUMBER, SUM(INVOICE.TURNOVER) = 0 AND the previous years turnover made for the INVOICE.DEBTOR_NUMBER, SUM(INVOICE.TURNOVER) is also 0, then fill the CUSTOMERS.CLASS_CUSTOMER field with the text 'E', where CUSTOMERS.DEBTOR_NUMBER = INVOICE.DEBTOR_NUMBER
```

As mentioned, we have no experience with PostgreSQL script. I hope someone can help us with this. An example script would also help a lot.

Comment: On an honest note since this is crucial to your business and not just a homework-question: Start hiring a DBA or offer some training for SQL in general (in the long run the company will benefit from the knowledge) - Postgres has some peculiarities but what you are looking for can be done with basic SQL-queries including some [comparison functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-comparison.html)..

Answer (score 1):

Setup data:

```
begin;
create temp table customer (DEBTOR_NUMBER int unique, customer_name text)
create temp table invoice (inv_id int, inv_date date,TURNOVER numeric, DEBTOR_NUMBER int  REFERENCES customers(DEBTOR_NUMBER));
commit;
```

Then one query:

```
 with a as (
select DEBTOR_NUMBER, sum(TURNOVER) filter 
(where inv_date> 2022-01-01) as total,
    case
        when total  > 100000 then 'AA'
        when total  > 20000 and total < 100000 then 'A'
        when total  > 6000 and total < 20000 then 'B'
        when total  > 0 and total < 6000 then 'C'
        when total  =0  then 'D'
    end as CLASS_CUSTOMER 
from invoice group by DEBTOR_NUMBER)
union
select distinct DEBTOR_NUMBER, 0, 'E'  
from invoice 
    where TURNOVER=0 and inv_date < '2022-01-01' )

select c.DEBTOR_NUMBER, a.total, 
c.customer_name, a.CLASS_CUSTOMER 
from a right join customer c on c.DEBTOR_NUMBER= a.DEBTOR_NUMBER;
```

---

Explanation:

- 2 tables: customer, invoice. DEBTOR_NUMBER as customer unique identifier.
- customer rating can write to query or write to a table. Here I just write a query, you can add it to a new column.
- the final query result is a table showing customer name, CLASS_CUSTOMER , and DEBTOR_NUMBER.
- postgtresql union [tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-union/),  Postgresql [sum filter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html)